# Does ehcache reserve (allocate) heap memory set with maxBytesLocalHeap?

Tags: memory-management, jvm, ehcache

I am using ehache v. 2.8.

But I am not sure if I understand the documentation correctly regarding reservation of the memory for the cache.

If the memory is set in `ehcache.xml` like this:

```
<ehcache maxBytesLocalHeap="256M">

(...)

</ehcache>
```

..will it actually be allocated at start and this cache will use **exactly 256MB** of heap or does this only mean (like it should, if this attribute is named like it is) that this cache can take **at most 256MB** of heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that this cache will do its best to contain **256MB or less** of user data.

But note that the actual memory footprint of the cache can be somewhat larger due to internal data structures.

Also in case the cache operates at full capacity, it may temporarily go over size while eviction takes place.

Comment: Thank you, I also came up with this but I wanted external confirmation. ;) Btw: do I get it correctly that ehcache does not preallocate because: a) there would be not benefit from it.., b) it would not be really possible within a JVM which uses a garbage colllector?

Comment: There is indeed not point in pre-allocating in the context of the JVM. It would force ehcache to "free" sections of the pre-allocation (however that is done - which is another question) every time there is an entry added to the cache. So that would mean more management thus more overhead.